# select column if not exists return as null - SQL

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark-sql

I have two possibilities to get data from two different tables: Table A and Table B.

The table B doesn't have one column(ColumnD), so I wanna to keep the full schema

I tried using Python(Spark):

```
#input argument
table_argument = 'B'

spark.sql(f'''
SELECT 
 ColumnA,
 ColumnB,
 ColumnC,
 CASE
   WHEN '{table_argument}' = 'B' THEN NULL
 ELSE ColumnD 
 END AS ColumnD
FROM {table_argument}''')
```

I got always the ERROR that is not possible to get the ColumnD. The When condition didn't work.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a nonexistent column, even in a `WHEN` clause that's not executed. You need to use a Python condition to construct that part of the query.

```
spark.sql(f'''
SELECT 
 ColumnA,
 ColumnB,
 ColumnC,
 {'NULL' if table_argument == 'B' else 'ColumnD'} AS ColumnD
FROM {table_argument}''')
```